# Laravel Google Map Markers

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, laravel-blade

I have this code I used to get the location of each order i receive..

```
        var map;
        var markers = <?php echo $order ?>; //this should dump a javascript array object which does not need any extra interperting.
        //var marks = []; //just incase you want to be able to manipulate this later

        function initMap() {
            var cent = {lat: {{$orderlat->Latitude }}, lng: {{ $orderlong->Longitude }} };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'), {
              zoom: 15,
              center: cent
            });
            $.each( markers, function( index, value ){
                var lokasi = new google.maps.LatLng({{$order[0]->Latitude }}, {{ $order[0]->Longitude }});
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: lokasi,
                  map: map
                });
            });
          }
```

For now it can only return 1 marker, because i was using this

```
var lokasi = new google.maps.LatLng({{$order[0]->Latitude }}, {{ $order[0]->Longitude }});
```

I understand I need to remove the 0 to get the rest, however i got an error which reads:

```
Property [Latitude] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

I also understand that to remove that error, I need to put them in a blade foreach, my question is, how do we insert blade in script tags? If impossible, what can I do? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the blade you can simple add  tag everywhere that you need:

```
<script>
     var app = 'dd';
</script>
```

this Code can add in for each and you add scripts that is related to Google map

here you can learn more about blade template system: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make an multi dimensional array of lat long and assign to jquery var

```
var marker_arr = '{{$marker_locations}}'
```

and at apply for loop on script to place marker on that location.

Hope this helps you.